# SELECT within SELECT for mysql query in java

Tags: java, sql

The first two "AND" statements work perfectly. When i am trying to import the third one i get no output.

```
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM album WHERE (Album_Title LIKE ?) AND (instrument LIKE ?) AND (ID_album ==(SELECT ID_album FROM song WHERE Song_Title LIKE ?))");
pst.setString(1,"%" + title_key + "%");
pst.setString(2,"%" + instr_key + "%");
pst.setString(3,"%" + song_key + "%");


ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: do you have a case in your database that fits all three criteria?

Comment: I changed every AND to OR and again..no output

Comment: This kind of search is notoriously hard for users to get right. You might want to investigate MySQL's FULLTEXT search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ==, You can try using 'IN'. Not sure if it will help, but you can try. Also, check if an entry is present in db.

Answer (score 1):

In *SQL* equals operator is `=` not `==`. Please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp for more information about operators in *where* clause